# GravityForm no enfoca formulario al devolver error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Estoy intentando que cuando al enviar formulario vacio en GravityForm, me devuelva el formulario con los errores enfocados. No logro obtenerlo o no estoy seguro si es que no se como hacerlo con Jquery. Ayuda, muchas gracias de adelantado.

Gravity Form devuelve un `div.validation_error` pero no se como interactuar con el mediante Jquery para hacer Scroll al ID de la seccion, ya que me scrollea con o sin el `div.validation_error` por igual.

Answer (score 1):

Después de una exhaustiva investigacion, lo logré haciendo lo siguiente:

```
$( "body, html" ).has( ".validation_error" ).animate( {
    scrollTop: $("#idSection").offset().top
} , 2000);
```

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema acá una respuesta útil.

*** Agregue a la respuesta la etiqueta html, ya que body no funciona en todos los navegadores. La etiqueta html hace que funcione para todos los demas basados o no en IE8.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco _qué_ hace el código? En tu pregunta dices que hace _scroll_ con o  sin `div.validation_error`, ¿esté código evita o asegura el scroll? De cualquier forma, gracias por compartir. No olvides que en 48 horas puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia colega, en este caso se trata de un formulario generado por GravityForm, el cual al intentar enviar campos vacios o con errores de validacion devuelve a la pagina del formulario con los `error_fields`, so...necesitaba hacer que el scroll fuera a parar a la section donde se encuentra el formulario, lograndolo con el codigo anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Existen dos opciones, si no tienes re-catpcha podrías habilitar ajax, con eso todo pasa en el mismo formulario y no hay refrescos de página, ahora si no lo activas puedes hacer lo siguiente en el **functions.php** debes agregar la siguiente linea:

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor', '__return_true' );
```

Con esto al hacer el submit, en la URL ira con el hash (#) seteado, por ende el navegador desplazara la página hasta el formulario.

Comment: La primera version se entrego. Probare tu sugerencia para la version siguiente. Gracias Jaime, un abrazo.